# Why replaceAll is not works?

Tags: java, regex

I have big with tags(parsed xml)

How to remove from string this elements:

```
    <Error>
        <Code></Code>
        <Text></Text>
        <Severity></Severity>
    </Error>
```

just

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("<Error>.*</Error>", "")
```

not works, error still in string..

Comment: `"(?s)<Error>.*?</Error>"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works, what does mean (?s) ?

And, why ? symbol after asterix?

Comment: `(?s)` = [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)